# VBA - TRANSPOSE in SUMPRODUCT

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate the scalar product of two vectors in VBA.

Since Excel has a function "SUMPRODUCT" that does this, I am trying to use it within VBA.

To that I want to transpose one of the two vectors, without wre-writing the whole vector in a Worksheet.

Is this possible in VBA?

Here is an example of mine that is not working at the moment:

```
X = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:C1").Value2
XT = Application.Transpose(X)

Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, 11).Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(XT,G1:G3)"
```

Comment: Why not transpose inside the SUMPRODUCT: `=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(A1:C1),G1:G3)`

Comment: You will need to use `.FormulaArray` to do it though.

Comment: As long as the ranges are fully populated with numbers MMULT function can do this: `=MMULT(A1:C1,G1:G3)`

Comment: Both of your answers worked like a charm! Is it possible though to add a variable to the cells, e.g.,`"=MMULT(A1:C"&i&",G1:G3)"` for **i** an integer number ,e.g., `i=1`? At the moment I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest  transposing the vector `A1:C1` within the formula. And we need to use `.FormulaArray` instead of `.Formula`. Try the following to replace your code example.

```
Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(1, 11).FormulaArray = _
            "=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(A1:C1),G1:G3)"
```

Comment: perfect this worked! Is it possible though to make the range within the TRANSPOSE formula variable, e.g.,  `"=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(A1:C"&i&"),G1:G3)"` for **i** a variable integer number?  At the moment I am getting an error

Comment: @Georgios Try `"=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(A" & i & ":C" & i & "),G1:G3)"`

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you very much. I honestly did not know that spaces after " did matter.